# How to enable logging of DynamoDB queries in the Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-dynamodb

I developed a Spring Boot (2.3.3) application which stores its data in DynamoDB.

I used the following packages to CRUD my data:

- aws-java-sdk-dynamodb (1.11.891)
- spring-data-dynamodb (5.1.0)

All works well, but I want to enable logging of requests my app makes to DynamoDB to be able to optimize it (use proper index, etc.).

I tried to configure log4j using this [AWS SDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-logging.html). But I still don't see any AWS SDK related lines in my app console output.

Please, help!

Answer (score 3):

For logging AWS dynamodb i use **log4j** and add following property in log4j.xml

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http.wire" level="trace"/>
```

This will print all calls which make to dynamodb server.

ref:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/logging-slf4j.html